# How to convert colors?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, comparison

I'd like to do some kind of special color comparison.
During my research I found out that the comparison should not be done using RGB spectrum because some different spectres like [HSL & HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) are designed to ***"more closely align with the way human vision perceives color-making attributes" (quote wikipedia)***.

So I need a way to convert different colorSystems into each other.

> One of the most important conversion for my purposes would be to convert HEX to HSL (using Swift)

---

Because I'm a bloody beginner this code is all that I've got so far:

```
// conversion HEX to HSL
HexToHSL("#F23CFF") // HSL should be "HSL: 296° 100% 62%"
func HexToHSL(_ hex: String) {
  let rgb = HexToRgb(hex)
  let r = rgb[0],
      g = rgb[1],
      b = rgb[2],
      a = rgb[3]

}

func RgbToHSL(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) -> [Int] {
    let r = r/255, g = g/255, b = b/255;

    let max = [r, g, b].max()!, min = [r, g, b].min()!;
    let (h, s, l) = Double(max + min)*0.5; // "Expression type 'Double' is ambiguous without more context"

    if (max == min) {
        h = s = 0; 
    } else {
        let d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        h /= 6;
    }
    return [ h, s, l ];
}
func HexToRgb(_ hex: String) -> [Int] {
    let hex = hex.substring(fromIndex: 1)
    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)
    let red = Int((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16),
    green = Int((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8),
    blue = Int(rgbValue & 0x0000FF),
    alpha = Int(255.0)
    return [red, green, blue, alpha]
}
```

Any help how to fix the color conversion from HEX to HSL would be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Note**: Theres also a [javascript sample](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256) for some kind of color conversion. Maybe it's helpful `:)`

**Edit**: I have fixed the code for rgb to hsl like this:

```
func RgbToHSL(_ rgb: [Int]) -> [Double] {
    let r = Double(rgb[0])/255, g = Double(rgb[1])/255, b = Double(rgb[2])/255;
    let max = [r, g, b].max()!, min = [r, g, b].min()!;
    var h = Double(max + min)*0.5,
        s = Double(max + min)*0.5,
        l = Double(max + min)*0.5;

    if (max == min) {
        h = 0
        s = 0
        l = 0
    } else {
        let d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);

        switch (max) {
          case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
          case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
          case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
          default:  break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }
    return [ h, s, l ];
}
```

... but the result for `rgb = [242, 60, 255]` will be `[0.8222222222222223, 1.0, 0.61764705882352944]` -- doesn't looks fine because it should be `296° 100% 62%`! :o

Comment: `[0.8222222222222223, 1.0, 0.61764705882352944]` *is* the correct result, the values are just scaled to the range 0.0...1.0. For example, 296/360 is 0.8222.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare colours, thus perform colour differences you need to use a perceptually uniform colourspace.

**[HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)** and **[HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)** are actually very poor colourspaces to do so, they should not be used for proper colorimetric computations because their *Lightness* and *Value* axis are not actual perceptual representation of *Luminance* contrary to colourspaces such as **[CIE L*a*b*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space)** and **[CIE L*u*v*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV)**.

There are multiple ways to compute colour difference in colour science, usually the simplest and the one assuming you are using a uniform colourspace is euclidean distance.

This is what **[DeltaE CIE 1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE76)** does using the **CIE L*a*b*** colourspace. The CIE noticed that some colours with low **DeltaE** values were actually appearing quite different, this was a side effect of **CIE L*a*b*** colourspace not being perceptually uniform enough. From there research has produced many new colour difference formulas and new perceptually uniform colourspaces.

Here is a non-exhaustive list from oldest to most recent of notable colour difference formulas and perceptually uniform colourspaces, notice the implementation complexity almost follows the list order:

- [DeltaE CIE 1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE76)
- [DeltaE CMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CMC_l:c_(1984))
- [DeltaE CIE 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE94)
- [DIN99](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN99-Farbraum)
- [IPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_appearance_model#IPT)
- [DeltaE CIE 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIEDE2000)
- [CIECAM02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIECAM02) & [CAM02-UCS](http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/col.20227)
- [CAM16 & CAM16-UCS](http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/col.22131)
- [ICTCP](https://www.dolby.com/us/en/technologies/dolby-vision/ICtCp-white-paper.pdf)
- [JzAzBz](https://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?URI=oe-25-13-15131)

I would suggest to look at something like **ICTCP** or **JzAzBz** which offer good performance and are not super complex to implement or at the very least use **CIE L*a*b*** with euclidean distance but avoid using **HSL** and **HSV**.

We have reference implementations for everything mentioned here in [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour).